# What do Small/Big eigenvalues indicate on?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If a matrix has:

1) Small eigenvalue

2) Big eigenvalue

3) Eigenvalue equal to one

What do each of them mean? Is there any conclusion about the matrix properties based upon its eigenvalue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalue is the number that the length of the eigenvector gets multiplied by.  If it is greater than $1$, repeated multiplications by the matrix will go off to infinity.  If it is less than $1$, repeated multiplications will (what?).  If it is $1$, repeated multiplications will (what?).

Comment: 0, same ???????

Comment: Are you guessing?  You should be able to prove these assertions and be sure.

Comment: $Mx=\lambda x$ so $M^n x = \lambda^n x$ it means $eigen(M^n)=\lambda^n$

Comment: I wonder in this case (whether eigenvalue is greater than one or not), why we do not consider the determinant? we can say the same thins $det(M^n)=det(M)^n$. However, eigenvalue is often considered to be a more important parameter than determinant for the sake of its magnitude. Any reason behind that?

Comment: Because the determinant being less than $1$ doesn't prove that all the eigenvalues are less than $1$.  Take diag$(2,1/3)$ for example.  The determinant is less than 1, but one eigenvalue is greater, so there are vectors that the matrix will send to infinity if you keep multiplying.